# MariaDB Galera Cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, mysql-cluster, mariadb

I ma trying setup MariaDB in cluster but looks like I stuck on this error:

```
#mysqld -u mysql
130407 21:36:24 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130407 21:36:24 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130407 21:36:24 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
130407 21:36:25 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
130407 21:36:26 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130407 21:36:27 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130407 21:36:29  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130407 21:36:30 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.30-MariaDB-30.1 started; log      sequence number 757767234118
130407 21:36:30 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown variable 'wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so'
130407 21:36:30 [ERROR] Aborting

130407 21:36:30  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130407 21:36:31  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 757767234118
130407 21:36:31 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Anyway whatever setting I put in my.cfg first with wsrep I am getting this error
ANy idea what is wrong?

this is my config:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
default_storage_engine  = InnoDB
log-bin=mysql-bin
binlog_format=ROW
server-id       = 510
sync_binlog=1
default-time-zone='US/Eastern'
log-slave-updates = 1
wsrep_provider = /usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address = gcomm://
wsrep_retry_autocommit = 0
wsrep_sst_method = rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=sst:sstpasswd
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_open_files = 2048
innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:2000M;ibdata2:2000M;ibdata3:100M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql/mysql_logs/
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2048M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 512M
innodb_log_file_size = 1536M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 50M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_write_io_threads = 32
innodb_read_io_threads = 32
innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
innodb_support_xa = false
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_doublewrite=0
```

So what step with this setup I am missing.
OS Arch Linux

```
#pacman -Q | grep galera
galera 23.2.2-2
#whereis libgalera_smm.so
libgalera_smm: /lib/libgalera_smm.so /usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so /lib64/libgalera_smm.so /usr/lib64/libgalera_smm.so

#mysqld -u mysql
130407 22:12:20 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130407 22:12:20 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130407 22:12:20 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
130407 22:12:20 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
130407 22:12:20 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130407 22:12:20 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130407 22:12:20  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130407 22:12:21 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.30-MariaDB-30.1 started; log    sequence number 761369976882
130407 22:12:21 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown variable 'wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so'
130407 22:12:21 [ERROR] Aborting

130407 22:12:21  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130407 22:12:22  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 761369976882
130407 22:12:22 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

???
And Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem, there was some bug with gcc version 4.7.2 (GCC) when i did downgrade to 4.2 all works fine, also if i use the generic package for galera all works too

Answer (score 1):

I see you have the line that the error output is telling you, but if this is on a 64bit system, you'll have to find the appropriate place for it. If you use the find command:

```
find / -name '*galera*'
```

You should see something that would resemble the libgalera_smm.so somewhere. Mine was under `/usr/lib64/libgalera_smm.so`.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your config, some of the options (like the wsrep_* ones) have to be in the [mysqld_safe] section, not in the [mysqld] section.

That's what your error is about:

> mysqld: unknown variable 'wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so'

"mysqld" does not know the variable "wsrep_provider", but "mysqld_safe" does know it.